# How access frame of a toView object in custom animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, frame

I want to make an animation like iOS home screen folders, and I have to know the frame of the final position of the "folder":[image: screen capture of the final view]

I'm using  a custom transition and here is the code of the animation file:

```
class FolderAnimationController: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    let duration    = 5.0
    var presenting  = true

    func transitionDuration(_ transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return duration
    }

    func animateTransition(_ transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView()
        let toViewC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)! as! ProjectViewController
        let fromViewC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)!as! ViewController

        let cell : FolderCollectionViewCell = fromViewC.folderCollectionView.cellForItem(at: (fromViewC.folderCollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()?.first!)!) as! FolderCollectionViewCell
        let cellSnapshot: UIView = cell.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)!
        let cellFrame = containerView.convert(cell.frame, from: cell.superview)
        cellSnapshot.frame = cellFrame
        cell.isHidden = true

        toViewC.view.frame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toViewC)
        toViewC.view.alpha = 0
        containerView.addSubview(toViewC.view)
        containerView.addSubview(cellSnapshot)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
            toViewC.view.alpha = 1.0

            let finalFrame = containerView.convert(toViewC.containerView.frame, from: toViewC.view)
            cellSnapshot.frame = finalFrame
            }) { (_) in
                cellSnapshot.removeFromSuperview()
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        }

    }
}
```

All works correctly, except `let finalFrame = containerView.convert(toViewC.containerView.frame, from: toViewC.view)` that set `finalFrame` values (is a CGRect variable) to `(origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 0, height = 0))`.

I've followed [this](http://dativestudios.com/blog/2013/09/29/interactive-transitions/) tutorial, writing my code in Swift

So, how can I access the property correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame is the zero rect because at the point you are accessing it, the view's layout pass has not occurred. After you set the `toVC.view` frame, add this line:

```
toVC.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

I've written about the use of snapshots in view controller transitions [here](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2016/03/13/better-snapshots/) if you're interested.

Comment: I want to access `toViewC.containerView.frame`, that is the rect of the "folder", as you can see i the screenshot. I've removed the conversion but it doesn't work...

Comment: But if I send `false` to  `completeTransition` I return to my first view

Comment: Ugh, I have done a terrible job on this answer for you. Sorry, I was also wrong about that.